# How to I apply filter while paginating in Asp.net MVC and entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

I have a web app that is written using ASP.NET MVC framework. In my `Homecontroller` I have an action called `Index` which responds to a `Get` request. In this action, I create pages using `IPagedList` library to break the records into multiple pages. My `Index@HttpGet` looks something like this

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    using(var connection = new Context())
    {
        int pageNumber = (id ?? 1);
        var presenter = new Presenter
        {
            Presenter = pageNumber,
            Tasks = connection.Tasks.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 30),
            Form = new TasksFiltersViewModel()
        }

        return View(presenter);
    }
}
```

I also have an action called `Index` that respond to the `Post` request which apply some filters. So in the `Post` request I do something like this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(Presenter model)
{
    int pageNumber = (id ?? 1);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using(var connection = new Context())
        {
            model.Tasks = connection.Tasks
                                    .Where(task => task.Status == 5)
                                    .ToPagedList(pageNumber, 30);
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

This also work fine unless the user changed the page then the filters are rest.

Here is how my presentation class looks like

```
public class Presenter
{
    public IPagedList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public TasksFiltersViewModel Form { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

How can I allow the users to use the pages while keeping the filters?

Here is my filters VM

```
public class TasksFiltersViewModel
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

The view looks like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Tasks", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Form.Status, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Form.Status, Model.Statuses, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Form.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-push-3">
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Filter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}

foreach (var task in Model.Tasks)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@task.Name</td>
        <td>@task.Type</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Details", "Task", new { @id = task.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })</td>
    </tr>
}


@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Tasks, id => Url.Action("Index", new { id }))
```

Comment: Use cookies maybe?

Comment: also naming the `DbContext` instance `connection` is not something I'd be comfortable with... .

Comment: You need to show your view, which I assume has a form that posts to the `Index()` method. It should have `FormMethod.Get` so it posts back to the GET method and that method includes parameters for the filters

Comment: Also show your `TasksFiltersViewModel` model

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated my question with what you requested

Comment: You did not show the `TasksFiltersViewModel` :) - Is its `Status` property the only thing your filtering on?

Comment: it is in there I just did not format it correctly. I just fixed it. I actually cut all my code down for the sake of simplicity and left only the `Status` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your form needs to post back to the GET method, and that method needs to include parameters for your filter properties. Your `PagedListPager` code in the view also need to include those filter properties so they are retained when you navigate to the next/previous page. Note that the `Index()` POST method is not used and can be deleted.

Having your model contain a complex object to the filter properties and extra complexity when binding, so start by changing your model to

```
public class Presenter
{
    public IPagedList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public int? Status { get; set; } // note nullable
    ... // add any other properties of TasksFiltersViewModel 
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the `Index()` method to

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? status) // add any other parameters your filtering on
{
    int pageNumber = (id ?? 1);
    var tasks = db.Tasks; // IQueryable<Task>
    if (status.HasValue)
    {
        tasks = tasks.Where(x => x.Status == status.Value)
    }
    if (otherParametersHaveValue)
    {
        tasks = tasks.Where(....);
    }
    Presenter model = new Presenter()
    {
        PageNumber = id ?? 1,
        Status = status,
        .... // set any other filter properties from the parameters
        Statuses = new SelectList(...),
        Tasks = tasks.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 30)
    };
    return View(model );
}
```

and change the view to

```
// Make the form a GET
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Tasks", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    ....
    // Modify expression based on revised model properties
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, Model.Statuses, ...)
}
....
// Add filter parameters to url so they are retained
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Tasks, id => Url.Action("Index", new { id, status = Model.Status })) // add other filter properties as required
```

Comment: Thank you. Instead of having to pass each filter as a parameter (I have like 4 filters) Isn't there a way to pass the TasksFiltersViewModel model to my Index@HttpGet method? TasksFiltersViewModel already encapsulate all of the filters.

Comment: If you have a lot of filter properties, you can modify the signature to `public ActionResult Index(int? id, [Bind(Prefix = "Form")]TasksFiltersViewModel filters)` - note the `Bind` attribute - And then in the `PagedListPager` - it would need to be `new { status = Model.Form.Status }` etc. And note that all the properties in `TasksFiltersViewModel` should be nullable to make building your query easier. Then modify the `Presenter` constructor to `Form = filters,`

Comment: One small issue that I have now. using `[Bind(Prefix = "Form")]TasksFiltersViewModel filters)` is great as I get the benefit of the two way binding. However, that will break the parameter coming from the pager URL. The User does not have a prefix "Form". any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You could just add an additional parameter for it - [Bind(Prefix = "Form")]TasksFiltersViewModel filters, int? page)` or set the `PageNumber ` property (I assume that's is what its for - and it so it really should be named `Page` to match the name used by the `PagedList`)

Comment: I guess is there a way to bind with an optional prefix? So the parameters "Form.Status" and "Status" in the request will be bind to the "Status" property. this way I can cover both requests

Answer (score 3):

I think a better way should be passing back to the view the filters in `ViewBag`.
You can make something like below:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
Model.Tasks, id => 
Url.Action("Index", new { id, 
Status = ViewBag.Status , AnotherFilterValue = ViewBag.AnotherFilterValue, ...  }))
```

But keep in mind to test `ViewBag.Status` for null value. If it does have a value put it in the route parameter list else set a default `ActionLink`.

Then inside the POST action you expect a nullable int like below:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? status, ...)
{
    int pageNumber = (id ?? 1);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    using(var connection = new Context())
    {
        if(status != null)
        {
          ViewBag.Status = status.value;
          model.Tasks = connection.Tasks
                                .Where(task => task.Status == status.value)
                                .ToPagedList(pageNumber, 30);
        }
        else
        {
           model.Tasks = connection.Tasks
                                  .ToPagedList(pageNumber, 30);
        }
      }
    }

   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Yes this should work. Had I seen this I wouldn't have written an answer :/

Comment: @gldraphael, There are reasons why this will not work, including the fact that OP's code in the form will not bind to those parameters. And then there is the really ugly `if/elseif` statements that would be required if there are more than one filter property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand that... what the OP is missing is not passing the filter parameters around. Once the OP gets that he'll be able to solve his problem :). I appreciate the detail in your answer though +1

Comment: I hate many `if/else` statements in code as well but he can pass the filter model in `ViewBag` and cast it. I think this case is useful when he has to pass two models, The first one for the data showed in the view and another one for filters. This situation stands in case if he does not want to encapsulate filters with other data in a single model which is recommended I think...

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this.

### The quick way: Cookies.

Just set a cookie for the filter options. On the actions where filtering is required, all you need to do is read the cookies and filter accordingly.
I dislike cookies and sessions, and would avoid them. But sometimes it could turn out to be what you need.

### Use GET parameters

In your example you've used `POST` to filter. Each time you click on a link, it fires a `GET` request, not a `POST`. So the filtering doesn't happen. The tricky part is making sure the `GET` parameters are set each time. Could create a custom extension similar to `Html.Action()` to start with. If you'll be checking the filter options in multiple actions, consider using an action `Filter`.