# Asp.net MVC 4.5 PagedList loose Filter values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello fellow Stackoverflowers,

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application. I currently have a PagedList, which I want to filter by date, which works fine on the first request.

My problem: When I click on the 2nd page link on the bottom of my paged list I'm loosing my current date, because of the new request.

It's a bit hard to find the error though:

My Paged List link:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.OfferList, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

My Search Form, pointing to Home Controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 well text-center">
            <h1>Offer Catalog</h1><br />
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OfferDateSearch.FromDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DatetimePickerFor(model => model.OfferDateSearch.FromDate, new DatePickerOption() { })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OfferDateSearch.FromDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My Home Controller:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
   ...

    public HomeVm HomeVm { get; set; }

    public HomeController()
    {
        HomeVm = new HomeVm();
        HomeVm.OfferDateSearch = new OfferDateSearchVM();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(HomeVm homeSearchVm, int page = 1)
    {
        // ... here I'm loosing my From Date, when clicking on 2nd page link
        if (homeSearchVm.OfferDateSearch != null)
        {
            HomeVm.OfferDateSearch.FromDate = homeSearchVm.OfferDateSearch.FromDate;
        }
        else
        {
            HomeVm.OfferDateSearch.FromDate = DateTime.Now;
        }

        //HomeVm.OfferList = OfferService.GetOfferList(page);

        return View(HomeVm);
    }
}
```

...and my Home ViewModel class:

```
public class HomeVm
{
    public HomeVm()
    {
        OfferListName = new OfferListVM();
    }
    public IPagedList<OfferListVM> OfferList { get; set; }
    public OfferDateSearchVM OfferDateSearch { get; set; }
}
```

..as well as the date vm:

```
public class OfferDateSearchVM
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "From")]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

}
```

Help very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your not sending any filter values in the request - it would need to be `@Html.PagedListPager(Model.OfferList, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, someFilter  = someValue, etc }))`

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450257/how-to-i-apply-filter-while-paginating-in-asp-net-mvc-and-entity-framework/42450564#42450564) for an example