# Bind a search viewmodel to Dropdownlist in IPage.PageList<FooModel>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view, which consists of several textbox fields, used for searching/filtering and the Index method on the controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string param1, string param2, string param3... string paramN)
```

This view receives a `PagedList.IPagedList<FooViewModel>`.

Based on [filter/search using multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153932/filter-search-using-multiple-fields-asp-net-mvc), it recommends to use a ViewModel to search/filter. Which makes sense as it will make the code simple, and manageable.

Refactor result would look like this:

```
Index(FooSearchViewModel)
```

ViewModel:

```
class FooSearchViewModel{
public List<string> Filters {get;set;}
public string SearchValue {get;set;}
}
```

I want to remove all the search fields and replace with a DropDownListFor html helper, that has a list of filter options(param1,param2,param3...paramN)

And only one textbox field, in which a searchvalue will be input.

So the question is, how can I bind the FooSearchViewModel to the DropDownList helper in Razor instead of `Paged.IPageList<FooViewModel>`

Comment: A `DropDownListFor()` generates a `<select>` for selecting a single option - it sounds like you want to pass back multiple values?

Comment: I want to pass back the ID of the selected option and value input into the single text field.

Comment: Then your view model needs 3 properties - `int SelectedFilter`, `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FilterList` and `string SearchValue` (so that you can use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFilter, Model.FilterList)` in the view

Comment: is this going to be the searchviewmodel just to clarify?

Comment: Yes, and it would also include your `IPagedList<T>` property for the paged list. Although its still not clear what your displaying in the dropdownlist - is that the list of column names?

Comment: Yes, it will be a list will contain column names in the dropdownlist.

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450257/how-to-i-apply-filter-while-paginating-in-asp-net-mvc-and-entity-framework/42450564#42450564) for an example - in that case its a dropdown to filter by a specific property value, but it would be a similar approach

Comment: thanks once again, it seems you always point me in the right directions on my recent questions :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153986/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-haris).

Comment: Just to clarify as well, I do not need to apply pagination while filtering