# Dropdown and searching filtering link ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Learning ASP.NET and I have a basic table (SQL database) which has data that I want to filter using a dropdown menu. I also already have implemented a basic search function and I want these two to work together. 
Right now the dropdown does nothing. It sees the right values but selecting a value does nothing.

Here is my controller: (I included parts of all the code)

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, string AddressFilter)
    {
        //Sorting parameters
        ViewBag.LastNameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "eLastName_desc" : ""; ......

var dbEmployee = db.Employee.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(s => s.eLastName, StringComparer.CurrentCulture);
        var employee = from s in dbEmployee select s;
        //Search
        if (searchString == null)
        { ........
           ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
        //Search functionality 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            employee = employee.Where(s => 
            s.eLastName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) || ......
```

Here's the code for the dropdown part.

```
           //Filter for dropdown, Address
        ViewBag.AddressFilter = (from s in db.Employee
                                   select s.eAddress).Distinct();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AddressFilter))
        {
            employee = employee.Where(s => s.eAddress.ToUpper().Contains(AddressFilter.ToUpper()));
        }



       int pageSize = 5;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(employee.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

And my View looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>Search here: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
<input type="submit" value="Search"/></p>
}
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<p>Department</p>@Html.DropDownList("Department", new 
SelectList(ViewBag.AddressFilter))


<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("eFirstName", "Index", new { sortOrder = 
ViewBag.FirstNameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("eLastName", "Index", new { sortOrder = 
ViewBag.LastNameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("eAddress", "Index", new { sortOrder = 
ViewBag.AddressSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("eSalary", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SalarySortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Department", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DepartmentSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
```

So I've obviously missed something and I can't find out what. (Side note, the Address is just city but I haven't changed the name yet).
Thank you for any suggestions or pointers

Comment: What are you wanting to do when an option is selected - all your have is the dropdownlist in a form which does not have a submit button. And why do you have 2 forms?

Comment: Thank you for the response, 
That second  @using Html.BeginForm shouldn't be there, probably a remnant of something else I tried before. 

What I'm trying to do is have the option I select in the drop down menu filter the table. the entities in my database have cities in which they live, the drop down correctly displayes these cities and what I want is when I select a city from the drop down, only the persons who live in that city should be displayed. A filter

Comment: Suggest you start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450257/how-to-i-apply-filter-while-paginating-in-asp-net-mvc-and-entity-framework/42450564#42450564) - use a view model and bind to your view model properties