# Html.Partial getting a input name on ActionResult and PagedList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have a `ActionResult` where I use `PagedList` to show some products, in this `ActionResult` I created a search to find all products or products by price. The problem is that I created it as a partial and now I'm trying to render it as `@HTML.Partial("_SearchProducts")`, it works well, but I can't get the input name from `_SearchProducts` on `ActionResult` to put it on `@Url.Action` to keep values of search.

How could I do this ?

**SearchProducts (Partial)**

```
<div class="panel panel-red">
    <div class="panel-body">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("showAnuncioPropIM", "Anuncio", FormMethod.Post, new { Class = "form-inline", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control money2" placeholder="Investimento mínimo USD$" id="min" name="min" size="25" style="z-index:0 !important;" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control money2" placeholder="Investimento máximo USD$" id="max" name="max" size="25" style="z-index:0 !important;" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
        }

    </div><!--/panel body-->
</div><!--/panel-->
```

**Products (ActionResult)**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<AddAnuncioIMModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "showAnuncioPropIM";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutConta.cshtml";
}



@Html.Partial("_SearchProducts")

<!--apresentacao-->
<div class="panel">    

    @if (Model.Count == 0){
        <h2 class="text-center">Nenhuma opção de investimento encontrada</h2>
    }
    else{
        <div class="row">
          @foreach (AddAnuncioIMModel m in Model){
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="panel panel-red">
                      <div class="panel-heading bg-red"><strong>Propriedade: #@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.id)</strong></div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Imagens/Anuncios/@Url.Content(m.imgExibicao)" /> 
                          <h5 class="text-center">Valor de Mercado</h5>
                          <h5 class="text-center" style="color:orange;font-weight:bold;">$@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.valorMercado)</h5>                         
                          <h5 class="text-center">Investimento</h5>
                          <h4 class="text-center" style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">$@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.valorInvestimento)</h4>
                          <h5 class="text-center">Previsão de Lucro</h5>
                          <h5 class="text-center" style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;">$@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.valorPrevLucro)</h5>
                          @*<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Comprar</a>*@
                          @Html.ActionLink("Comprar", "detailAnuncioIM", "Anuncio", new { id = EncodingParams.encode(Convert.ToString(@m.id)) }, new { Class = "btn btn-success btn-block" })
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          }
        </div>
        <p>Página @Model.PageNumber de @Model.PageCount</p>
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("showAnuncioPropIM", new { pagina = page, min = min, max = max }))
    }
</div>
<!--/apresentacao-->
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult showAnuncioPropIM(int? pagina, decimal? min, decimal? max){
            int tamanhoPagina = 20;
            int numeroPagina = pagina ?? 1;

            IList<AnuncioIM> _lista = new List<AnuncioIM>();
            IList<AddAnuncioIMModel> _listaModel = new List<AddAnuncioIMModel>();

            try{
                decimal valMin = min ?? 0;
                decimal valMax = max ?? 0;
                if (valMax > 0){
                    _lista = new AnuncioIMDAO().findAllAnunciosByValorMinMax(valMin, valMax);
                }else{
                    _lista = new AnuncioIMDAO().findAllByValor();
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                Debug.WriteLine("AnuncioController showAnuncioPropIM: " + e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            foreach (AnuncioIM x in _lista){
                AddAnuncioIMModel model = new AddAnuncioIMModel();
                model.id = x.id;
                model.valorMercado = x.valorMercado;
                model.valorInvestimento = x.valorInvestimento;
                model.valorPrevLucro = x.valorPrevLucro;
                model.banheiros = x.pesquisa.banheiros;
                model.quartos = x.pesquisa.quartos;
                model.m2 = x.pesquisa.m2;
                model.imgExibicao = x.imagens[0].nome;
                _listaModel.Add(model);
            }

            return View(_listaModel.ToPagedList(numeroPagina, tamanhoPagina));
        }
```

Comment: Your form should be making a GET to the `view()` method, not a POST to `showAnuncioPropIM()`. You need to show your controller code

Comment: @StephenMuecke done !

Comment: But that is your GET method that returns your PagedList. Now I'm confused because you have `Url.Action("view", ...)` in your `@Html.PagedListPager()`

Comment: In any case, you need to return the values of `min` and `max` back to the view, either using `ViewBag` properties, or better a view model containing those properties and a `IPagedList<AnuncioIM>` property

Comment: For an example, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450257/how-to-i-apply-filter-while-paginating-in-asp-net-mvc-and-entity-framework/42450564#42450564)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I made. I followed your suggestion about use GET instead of POST and now it works. I just used `min = @Request["min"], max = @Request["max"]` Thanks for your attention.

Comment: That's a pretty ugly approach, and when the view is returned, the textboxes for `min` and `max` will be empty again (poor user might not even remember what they have filter it by. Use a view model and strongly bind to it :)

Comment: And your not getting any validation (what is the user enters a `max` which is less that `min`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I get your point. I will do this. But how could I pass a model value to a partial as example min and max in this issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156825/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-fernandopaiva).