# PagedList loses search filter on second page and after pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I lose all data on the second page, an there after.The first results/page shows up with correct data. The second page and there after, no data.

**My code :**

```
public ActionResult Contact(int? pageNumber, string search, string option, string select)
    {
        if (option == "Company")
        {            
            return View(db.CompaniesServers.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search)).ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 2));
        }
        else
        {
            return View(db.CompaniesServers.ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 3));
        }
    }
```

**My View :**

```html
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@model IPagedList<WorkingWithData.Models.CompaniesServer>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
            {

    <b>
        Search Options: <br />
    </b>@Html.RadioButton("option", "Company") <text>Company Name</text> 
    @Html.TextBox("search", null, new { style = "height:30px" })  <select id="serverList" style="height:33px; font-size:small" class="btn btn-default">
                    <option value="All">Select Server</option>
                    <option value="10.67.21.40">Lam Server 4</option>
                    <option value="10.67.21.47">Lam Server 14</option>
                    <option value="10.67.21.70">Lam Server 12</option>
                </select> <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Home/Contact">Reset</a>    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
                
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
           Address
        </th>
        <th>
           Port
        </th>
        <th>
           Name
        </th>
        <th>
          Environment
        </th>
        <th>
           Active
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Port)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Environment)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, pageNumber => Url.Action("Contact", new
{
    pageNumber
}))
```

The first page results return valid info. But as soon as I go into the second page, nothing appears. My variables return null when debugging.

Should I do try and stop a page load? New with MVC though.

Comment: What variables are you referring to? (your not sending anything in the url for `search`, `option`, or `select` so they will always be `null`)

Comment: If you are wanting to keep the search/filtering, then refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450257/how-to-i-apply-filter-while-paginating-in-asp-net-mvc-and-entity-framework/42450564#42450564) for an example

Answer (score 5):

My workaround is to use a ViewBag in the controller, im not sure how you could implement it in your code but may help you

View:

```
@model IPagedList<MyModel>
    <div class="pagedList">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, search = ViewBag.search }),
       PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText)
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string search = null, int page = 1)
        {
            ViewBag.search = search;
            var model = _db.Employees
                .Where(r => search == null || r.Name.StartsWith(search) || r.Name.Contains(search))
                .Select(r => new EmployeeViewModel
                {
                    Id = r.Id,
                    Name = r.Name,
                    City = r.City,
                    Country = r.Country,
                }).ToPagedList(page, 10);
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! As soon as I saw your post, I realised I wasn't sending back my options and search back to my paging. So I used Viewbag to send/store them.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I really didn't want to use `ViewBag`, but I had to. Seems I needed to store/send back my 'option' and 'search' values back, with every paging. At first, I was just storing the 'pageNumber' only.

Added in my controller:

```
 ViewBag.Search1 = option;
 ViewBag.Search2 = search;
```

Into view, added on the paging section of `PagedListPager`:

```
option = ViewData["Search1"];
search = ViewData["Search2"];
```

Comment: Use a view model, not `ViewBag` (and Mochuelo already noted that in their answer, so you should have accepted that rather than adding your own answer)

Comment: Whose Mochuelo?

Comment: The user who added the other answer

Comment: I agree with user3559349. You should have accepted Mochuelo's answer as the correct answer as opposed to taking his help, rewording it to your exact code and reposting.