# How to save input value after submit form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, pagination

I am working on a Asp.net core 2 project. As part of my project, I need to look at the results with the paging. look at image please

[image]

after submitted search form the value of `input` deleted.

[image]

And when I Click on page 2, I can not see the rest of the results
How can i save input value after submitted form?

**Controller**

```
 public IActionResult SearchResult(string txtsearch, int page = 1)
    {
        var model = new IndexModel();
        if (txtsearch != null)
        {
            //Paging/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            int paresh = (page - 1) * 3;
            int count = _iuw.NewsRepositoryUW.Get(n => n.Title.Contains(txtsearch)).Count();

            ViewBag.PageID = page;
            double counter = count % 3;
            if (counter != 0)
            {
                ViewBag.PageCount = (count / 3) + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.PageCount = count / 3;
            }

            model.searchModel = _iuw.NewsRepositoryUW.Get(n => n.Title.Contains(txtsearch)).Skip(paresh).Take(3).ToList();
            if (model.searchModel.Count() > 0)
            {
                ViewBag.searchVal = txtsearch;
                return View("Searchresult", model);
            }
            else
            {
                model.searchModel = null;
            }
        }
        return View("Searchresult", model);
    }
```

**search form**

```
             <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" asp-action="SearchResult" asp-controller="Home" method="get">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="txtsearch" name="txtsearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: You need to pass a model to your view containing both a property for the search value and your `IEnumerable<T>` property, and bind to the search property (using a `HtmlHelper` or TagHelper

Comment: Refer [How to I apply filter while paginating in Asp.net MVC and entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450257/how-to-i-apply-filter-while-paginating-in-asp-net-mvc-and-entity-framework/42450564#42450564) for an example using a dropdownlist for the filter

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephen Muecke suggested , you can add search property to your model and use TagHelper for the search property .

If you want to implement your requirement without using model binding , base on your codes, you could try :

```
 <input type="text" id="txtsearch" name="txtsearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" value="@(ViewBag.txtsearch ?? String.Empty)">
```

And set value in controller :

```
ViewBag.txtsearch = txtsearch;
```